# MBProgressHUD is not changing to customView

Tags: ios, grand-central-dispatch, mbprogresshud

I am running around the issue, that MBProgressHUD should be updating its View with a Checkmark/X for succeeded/failed requests. Somehow this doesnt really work as intended and the update only works after all the code has executed.

#### initializing the HUD

```
  ...
  MBProgressHUD *hud = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];
  hud.labelText = @"Verifying Credit Card";
  _HUD = hud;

  CWAPIClient *client = [CWAPIClient sharedClient];
  client.delegate = self;
  dispatch_queue_t backgroundQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.clubw.billing", 0);
  dispatch_async(backgroundQueue, ^{
    [client save:billingProfile with:[Address defaultBillingAddress]];
  });
  ....
```

#### Callback to process information:

```
self POST:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"user/%@/billingprofile", [[Profile defaultProfile] userId]] parameters:params success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
      dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self.delegate CWAPIClient:self doneVerifyingCreditCard:responseObject];
      });
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
      NSLog(@"%@", error);
    }];
```

#### callback when action is complete

```
BOOL success = [[jsonResponse objectForKey:@"success"] boolValue];
  if (success)
  {

    NSLog(@"Thread: %@", [NSThread currentThread]);
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

      UIImage *checkmarkImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"checkmark.png"];
      UIImageView *checkmarkView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:checkmarkImage];

      _HUD.customView = checkmarkView;
      _HUD.labelText = @"Credit Card Verified!";
      _HUD.mode = MBProgressHUDModeCustomView;
      NSLog(@"Thread: %@", [NSThread currentThread]);

      sleep(5);
      [_HUD hide:YES];
    });
```

After the 5 seconds, it simply closed the HUD - and the updated one flashes for a second. 
It seems, like this is a threading issue - but I cant seem to figure out where it is throwing up.

Answer (score 0):

In the portion of the code where you make your callback, be sure to perform the callback on the main queue as well.

Comment: Already have it on the Main Thread, sadly it doesnt seem like it wants to update.